# Cannot use Chrome through an RDP session

Tags: google-chrome, gpu, rdp

I cannot use Chrome through an RDP session. When connected without RDP, chrome works fine. However, when used within and RDP session, Chrome times out on every attempt to load a web page.

Answer (score 1):

One must change the default GPU acceleration to disabled.

Go to: chrome://flags/ 
Then, look for the GPU acceleration flag and set it to false.